# Python mysql error #1064

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to store the data into MySQL by writing pipeline, but it occurs:

> _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064,"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc,pic)values ('xe4\xbe\x9b\xe5\xba.......' at line 1")

Here is my code:

```
def __init__(self):
    #self.file = codecs.open('tutorial_data.json','wb',encoding='utf-8')
    self.dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool('MySQLdb',
                                        host = 'localhost',
                                        port = 3306,
                                        db = 'project',
                                        user = 'root',
                                        passwd = '',
                                        cursorclass = MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor,
                                        charset = 'utf8',
                                        use_unicode = True)
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    query = self.dbpool.runInteraction(self._conditional_insert, item)
    query.addErrback(self.handle_error)
    return item

def _conditional_insert(self,tx,item):

        tx.execute(
        "INSERT INTO raw (title,area,date,sclass,desc,pic )\ 
         VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",

               (item['title'][0],
                item['area'][0],
                item['date'][0],
                item['sclass'][0],
                item['desc'][0],
                item['pic'][0])
                )
```

My MySQL version is 5.6.17 and mysql-python version is 1.2.5_

Answer (score 1):

`DESC` is a [reserved keyword in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-6.html). If you are going to name a column identifier `DESC` you *must* wrap it in ticks:

```
 tx.execute(
    "INSERT INTO raw (title,area,date,sclass,`desc`,pic )\ 
     VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
```

However, a better solution would be to not use a reserved keyword as a column identifier as it can cause confusing and potential errors elsewhere (plus the full word "description" is clearer and makes for more maintainable code).

```
 tx.execute(
    "INSERT INTO raw (title,area,date,sclass,description,pic )\ 
     VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
```

Comment: BIG THX! I am too careless